# Remove rows that have inexact duplicates in R

Tags: r, if-statement, duplicates

I have some sales data where mistakes recorded at the point of sale are corrected afterward and the data set still contains records for the initial mistake then a duplicate of the mistake but with a negative price value. However, there are multiple duplicate lines for some sales which are valid and must be retained.

```
DATE    MODEL   TYPE    COUNT   PRICE   WEIGHT  TOTAL   ABS_COUNT   ABS_WEIGHT  ABS_TOTAL   replicate
20140211    JBL A   1   4.5 15  67.5    1   15  67.5    1
20140211    JBL A   1   4.5 15  67.5    1   15  67.5    2
20140211    JBL B   1   6.5 27  175.5   1   27  175.5   1
20140211    JBL A   1   4   11  44  1   11  44  1
20140211    JBL B   1   11.2    44  492.8   1   44  492.8   1
20140211    JBL B   1   6.5 27  175.5   1   27  175.5   2
20140211    JBL B   1   11.2    44  492.8   1   44  492.8   2
20140211    JBL A   1   4.5 15  67.5    1   15  67.5    3
20140211    JBL A   1   4.5 15  67.5    1   15  67.5    4
20140211    JBL B   -1  -11.2   44  -492.8  1   44  492.8   3
20140211    JBL B   1   10.9    82  893.8   1   82  893.8   1
20140211    JBL A   1   4.5 15  67.5    1   15  67.5    5
20140211    JBL A   1   4.5 15  67.5    1   15  67.5    6
20140211    JBL A   1   4.5 15  67.5    1   15  67.5    7
20140211    JBL B   1   11.2    44  492.8   1   44  492.8   4
20140211    JBL A   1   3.2 15  48  1   15  48  1
20140211    JBL B   1   11.2    44  492.8   1   44  492.8   5
20140211    JBL B   1   11.2    44  492.8   1   44  492.8   6
20140211    JBL A   1   4.5 15  67.5    1   15  67.5    8
20140211    JBL A   1   4.5 15  67.5    1   15  67.5    9
20140211    JBL B   1   11.2    104 1164.8  1   104 1164.8  1
20140211    JBL A   -1  4.5 -15 -67.5   1   15  67.5    10
20140211    JBL A   1   4.5 15  67.5    1   15  67.5    11
20140211    JBL A   1   4.5 15  67.5    1   15  67.5    12
20140211    JBL B   1   11.2    44  492.8   1   44  492.8   7
```

What I have done is calculated the abs() for each of the COUNT, WEIGHT, and TOTAL columns then counted the number of replicates.  I am now trying to figure out how to remove the negative observations as well as the corresponding duplicate where column replicate=n-1

```
test$ABS_COUNT <- abs(test$COUNT)
test$ABS_WEIGHT <- abs(test$WEIGHT)
test$ABS_TOTAL <- abs(test$TOTAL)`

test2 <- test %>%
  dplyr::group_by(DATE, MODEL, TYPE, PRICE, ABS_COUNT, ABS_WEIGHT, ABS_TOTAL) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(replicate=seq(n()))%>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: How do you identify the duplicate rows? based in which columns do you determine they're dups?

Comment: There is no system to determine which is the exact duplicate, I have been informed that I am to simply remove one of the corresponding positive entries. (I didn't design the system, I just have to work with it).  I also have to remove these instances across +500,000 transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach. First, I add an "iteration" column to count how many of the given transaction has occurred. Then I anti-join (keeping only non-matches) with itself, but where the PRICE and COUNT have reversed sign. This means only the originals that don't have a negative match are kept. We go from 25 rows to 21, since the two reversing entries also cancel their original counterparts.

It looks like the two reversing entries, in rows 10 and 22, each have -1 COUNT and a negative price, but in one case this was achieved though negative PRICE and once through negative WEIGHT. So it seems like using COUNT and TOTAL for the anti-join would be more reliable than including PRICE and WEIGHT, which aren't both reversed in a reversing entry.

```
library(dplyr)
temp <- df %>%
  select(DATE:TOTAL) %>%  # Just the original data
  group_by(DATE, MODEL, TYPE, COUNT, TOTAL) %>%
  mutate(iteration = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

df2 <- temp %>% 
  anti_join(temp %>% 
               filter(TOTAL < 0) %>% 
               mutate(COUNT = -COUNT, TOTAL = -TOTAL) %>% 
              select(DATE:COUNT, TOTAL, iteration))

> df2
# A tibble: 21 x 8
       DATE MODEL TYPE  COUNT PRICE WEIGHT TOTAL iteration
      <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <dbl>  <int> <dbl>     <int>
 1 20140211 JBL   A         1   4.5     15  67.5         2
 2 20140211 JBL   B         1   6.5     27 176.          1
 3 20140211 JBL   A         1   4       11  44           1
 4 20140211 JBL   B         1   6.5     27 176.          2
 5 20140211 JBL   B         1  11.2     44 493.          2
 6 20140211 JBL   A         1   4.5     15  67.5         3
 7 20140211 JBL   A         1   4.5     15  67.5         4
 8 20140211 JBL   B         1  10.9     82 894.          1
 9 20140211 JBL   A         1   4.5     15  67.5         5
10 20140211 JBL   A         1   4.5     15  67.5         6
# … with 11 more rows
```